# In pose mode how do I turn bone to line up with Y axis if I can't type coordinates?

Tags: bones, axis

Using the Z axis how do I rotate the bone to match up with the Y axis line in pose mode, because according to transform tab the rotation section is all zeros so I can't just type it down since the bone thinks it's in the right positon.[image]

Comment: Is the bone's default pose not aligned with XYZ?

Comment: Well, the bone has an Autopath constraint so right now you're seeing it following the direction of the path however I moved it off the path. Sorry I didn't mention it before I knew there was something I forgot.